# How to replace catch block in *.java using sed?

Tags: unix, shell, sed, awk

How to replace the following pattern in a java project

```
catch(SQLException e) {
       \\TO DO

}
```

with

```
catch(SQLException e) { S.O.P(); }
```

Please note that the file will have other patterns like

```
catch(IOException e) {
    // To Do }
```

which should not be changed.

I tried

```
sed 's/catch\(SQLException[^\}]*}/catch(SQLException e)\{S.O.P();\}/g' file.java
```

but it does not work.

Comment: In general, you don't want to do such kind of things using regular expressions because Java is not a regular language. You need a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use awk

```
$ more file
catch(SQLException e) {
       \\TO DO

}
catch(IOException e) {
    // To Do }

$ awk -vRS="}" '/catch\(SQLException e\)/{$0="catch(SQLException e) { S.O.P();" }NR{print $0RT}  ' file
catch(SQLException e) { S.O.P();}

catch(IOException e) {
    // To Do }
```

Explanation: sEt the record separator to `}`. Then check for `SQLException`. If found, set the record `$0` to the new one. No complicated regex required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Perl script:

```
use strict;

my $file = '';
$file.=$_ while(<>);
$file=~s[catch\s*\(\s*SQLException\s*(\w+)\)\s*\{.*?\}][catch(SQLException $1) { S.O.P(); }]sg;
print $file."\n";
```

Sample run:

Input file:

```
try { int a = 0/0; }
catch(SQLException e) {
\\TO DO
}
catch(MyOwnException e){
// MORE THINGS
}
finally{
```

Result:

```
try { int a = 0/0; }
catch(SQLException e) { S.O.P(); }
catch(MyOwnException e){
// MORE THINGS
}
finally{
```

Comment: hmm according to OP's definition, `MyOwnException` should not be changed.